# Shorthand to a span to text if variable is set?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I had a very nice declaration of variables:

```
var text = option.text(),
    attr,
    li,
    attr = {
        'class': 'option',
        html: text,
        data: {
            option: option
        },
        css: {
            display: 'block'
        }
    },
    li =  $j('<li/>', attr);
```

Now I need to add a span to the text if it exists, like this:

```
var option = $j(this),
    text = option.text(),
    attr,
    li;

if(typeof option.data('alt') !== 'undefined') {
    text += '<span class="alt">' + option.data('alt') + '</span>';
}

attr = {
    'class': 'option',
    html: text,
    data: {
        option: option
    },
    css: {
        display: 'block'
    }
};
```

Is there any way to add the span inline with a bit less code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
if(typeof option.data('alt') !== 'undefined'){
  text += '<span class="alt">'+option.data('alt')+'</span>';
}
```

Try ternary operator:

```
text += option.data('alt') ? '<span class="alt">'+option.data('alt')+'</span>' : '';
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
text+= (typeof option.data('alt') !== 'undefined')?'<span class="alt">' + option.data('alt') + '</span>':'';
```

Answer (score 0):

A little bit less, but not all that much:

```
var text = option.text() + (typeof option.data('alt') !== 'undefined'
                            ? '<span class="alt">' + option.data('alt') + '</span>'
                            : ''),
    attr,
    li,
    // ...
```

If you know that `option.data('alt')` won't be *falsey* even if it's there, you can shorten that a lot:

```
var text = option.text() + (option.data('alt')
                            ? '<span class="alt">' + option.data('alt') + '</span>'
                            : ''),
    attr,
    li,
    // ...
```

...because the test will be false for `null`, `""`, `undefined`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!option.data('alt')) text += '<span class="alt">'+option.data('alt')+'</span>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Since we're codegolfing here I suppose we can propose dirty things and even remove the  closing tags:

```
text+= (typeof option.data('alt') !== 'undefined')?'<span class="alt">' + option.data('alt'):'';
```

If you add this text to the DOM you should get the closing tags anyway.